# There is a way to put name dynamically in arrays or it's positions?

Tags: javascript

**What I have:**

**3 database with a lot of animals**, there is a lot of similiarities between the tables, **so with a one query**, bring every one based on a **'name, register or code'** and **return in a array of objects in PHP and pass it to Javascript objects and make a array of those js objects.**
Since the DB it's really huge, i've limited the query **to bring just 60 animals** from every DB.

Right now, i print them on a table and **call a function that calls a modal**, on that modal **using a function onClick** when the user click to open it (modal), i **pass the position** on that JS **array of objects** in a parameter and then it will print the information inside of the object in that modal.

**The Problem:**

I am using a **'static'** way to do this, where **i just print 0 to 60** and i **check in a if what DB is**, and if it's not the first one $i = 60; so it began again to count from 60 to 120, and i do another to print a id to say it's from 120 to 180.

`listAnimals(animal[id]);`

where **this `id` is the number i print in a static way**, so when i don't bring the full list of 180 animals which means that the user searched for a certain 'name, code or register' it will always print the wrong number, because it's static, so it will show wrong information on my modal or it will show none, since that position on `animal['id']` doens't exist.

Example: let's say i seach a '123456' code on my search engine, it will bring 3 diferents results from the 3 db, **the first one will have an ID of 0, with will show the correct information on the modal**, **but the second one it's from the second db, and it will come with 60 but since there it's none id 60 on the JS array of objects**, just 3 it will not show any of the information, and of course this will happen to the third one since it's id will be 120.

**What i wanted to do:**

To not use a position on that JS array and start to use Key > Value (hash table i guess?) to say that the KEY will be the same as the animal register on the DB table, like, when call the the function animals(animal[register]) it will print the animal with that register, since it exist, so i will always call then by registers (since it's unique) and always print the right animal.

What i've tried to do:

`Let animal {
 id: receive id from php,
 name: receive name from php,
 register: receive it from php
}
animals[animal.register] = animal

listAnimals[animal.register];
`

Example: 
I search for a animal with the register '12345'

PHP will look for me on the DBs after will return a Array of Objects with all animals that contain that register.

In JS i will define a Object inside a for that will receive the Array information of all objects inside the PHP array.

```
    animals = []
    for ($i = 0; $i < count(animals); $i++) {
      let Animal = {
       id: <?php echo animal.getId(); ?>,
       name: <?php echo animal.getName(); ?>,
       register: <?php echo animal.getregister(); ?>
     }
    animals[Animal.register] = Animal
    }

    function listAnimals(animals) {
       return to the modal the animal equivalent of that register
    }
```

What i am trying to do right now it's to use [Maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: Can you share full code

Comment: So is this a JavaScript question or a PHP question?  They are quite different, and the only code you're showing is JavaScript.

Comment: sorry i was using php to put the values on my object and i forgot about that, i posted the full code, if i can solve it with php it's ok too but my back end i use pure php and on my front i use plain* JS + Jquery

Comment: Need to show loop and what `$i` is doing and and example of what _animal on position 1234 receive the animal with 1234 id_ means.  This should be easy in PHP.

Comment: for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($animais); $i++) { my code } and animais['1234'] = animal with the id property = '1234', on the array animals, there is a lot of keys, the key 1234 represents the animal with the id 1234, so the id on the database and the position name on the id animais it's the same

Comment: Your question isvery Unclear.  However I can firmly advise that you should be building the full data structure in php (as a multidimensional array with ids as first level keys), then when the array is fully built, call `json_encode()` to pass it as an object to javascript.  Manually creating this js object is heavy-handed and might result in a broken script.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I solved it, the problem is that JavaScript need a string as a key so what I did? I join the ID who comes from the db with their initial, so in the end it will end something like this

> foo123456

And then I can easily work with Key > Value arrays where a Key is a String and represents a single objects (value). It was also good for my case where I needed a little difference between the ids that come from the dbs. I also tried to do it in PHP and it was a lot easier, later I will try to implement the JSON one.